# How do I get a 50MB zip file with a 600MB xml file into a mysql datatable?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, zip, xml-namespaces

How do I get a 50MB zip file with a 600MB xml file (over 300,000 "<"abc:ABCRecord">") into a mysql datatable? The xml file itself has the following structure:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<abc:ABCData xmlns:abc="http://www.abc-example.com" xmlns:xyz="http:/www.xyz-example.com">
<abc:ABCHeader>
<abc:ContentDate>2015-08-15T09:03:29.379055+00:00</abc:ContentDate>
<abc:FileContent>PUBLISHED</abc:FileContent>
<abc:RecordCount>310598</abc:RecordCount>
<abc:Extension>
  <xyz:Sources>
    <xyz:Source>
      <xyz:ABC>5967007LIEEXZX4LPK21</xyz:ABC>
      <xyz:Name>Bornheim Register Centre</xyz:Name>
      <xyz:ROCSponsorCountry>NO</xyz:ROCSponsorCountry>
      <xyz:RecordCount>398</xyz:RecordCount>
      <xyz:ContentDate>2015-08-15T05:00:02.952+02:00</xyz:ContentDate>
      <xyz:LastAttemptedDownloadDate>2015-08-15T09:00:01.885686+00:00</xyz:LastAttemptedDownloadDate>
      <xyz:LastSuccessfulDownloadDate>2015-08-15T09:00:02.555222+00:00</xyz:LastSuccessfulDownloadDate>
      <xyz:LastValidDownloadDate>2015-08-15T09:00:02.555222+00:00</xyz:LastValidDownloadDate>
     </xyz:Source>
    </xyz:Sources>
   </abc:Extension>
 </abc:ABCHeader>
<abc:ABCRecords>
 <abc:ABCRecord>
 <abc:ABC>5967007LIEEXZX4LPK21</abc:ABC>
  <abc:Entity>
    <abc:LegalName>REGISTERENHETEN I Bornheim</abc:LegalName>
    <abc:LegalAddress>
      <abc:Line1>Havnegata 48</abc:Line1>
      <abc:City>Bornheim</abc:City>
      <abc:Country>NO</abc:Country>
      <abc:PostalCode>8900</abc:PostalCode>
    </abc:LegalAddress>
    <abc:HeadquartersAddress>
      <abc:Line1>Havnegata 48</abc:Line1>
      <abc:City>Bornheim</abc:City>
      <abc:Country>NO</abc:Country>
      <abc:PostalCode>8900</abc:PostalCode>
    </abc:HeadquartersAddress>
    <abc:BusinessRegisterEntityID register="Enhetsregisteret">974757873</abc:BusinessRegisterEntityID>
    <abc:LegalForm>Organisasjonsledd</abc:LegalForm>
    <abc:EntityStatus>Active</abc:EntityStatus>
  </abc:Entity>
  <abc:Registration>
    <abc:InitialRegistrationDate>2014-06-15T12:03:33.000+02:00</abc:InitialRegistrationDate>
    <abc:LastUpdateDate>2015-06-15T20:45:32.000+02:00</abc:LastUpdateDate>
    <abc:RegistrationStatus>ISSUED</abc:RegistrationStatus>
    <abc:NextRenewalDate>2016-06-15T12:03:33.000+02:00</abc:NextRenewalDate>
    <abc:ManagingLOU>59670054IEEXZX44PK21</abc:ManagingLOU>
  </abc:Registration>
</abc:ABCRecord>
<abc:ABCRecord>
  <abc:ABC>5967007LIE45ZX4MHC90</abc:ABC>
  <abc:Entity>
    <abc:LegalName>SUNNDAL HOSTBANK</abc:LegalName>
    <abc:LegalAddress>
      <abc:Line1>Sunfsalsvegen 15</abc:Line1>
      <abc:City>SUNNDALSPRA</abc:City>
      <abc:Country>NO</abc:Country>
      <abc:PostalCode>6600</abc:PostalCode>
    </abc:LegalAddress>
    <abc:HeadquartersAddress>
      <abc:Line1>Sunndalsvegen 15</abc:Line1>
      <abc:City>SUNNDALSPRA</abc:City>
      <abc:Country>NO</abc:Country>
      <abc:PostalCode>6600</abc:PostalCode>
    </abc:HeadquartersAddress>
    <abc:BusinessRegisterEntityID register="Foretaksregisteret">9373245963</abc:BusinessRegisterEntityID>
    <abc:LegalForm>Hostbank</abc:LegalForm>
    <abc:EntityStatus>Active</abc:EntityStatus>
  </abc:Entity>
  <abc:Registration>
    <abc:InitialRegistrationDate>2014-06-26T15:01:02.000+02:00</abc:InitialRegistrationDate>
    <abc:LastUpdateDate>2015-06-27T15:02:39.000+02:00</abc:LastUpdateDate>
    <abc:RegistrationStatus>ISSUED</abc:RegistrationStatus>
    <abc:NextRenewalDate>2016-06-26T15:01:02.000+02:00</abc:NextRenewalDate>
    <abc:ManagingLOU>5967007LIEEXZX4LPK21</abc:ManagingLOU>
  </abc:Registration>
</abc:ABCRecord>
</abc:ABCRecords>
</abc:ABCData>
```

How does the mysql table need to look like and how can I accomplish this? The goal is to have all the abc tagged content in the table. In addition, there will be a new zip file each day provided via a download link and it should update the table each day. The zip files are named after the following structure: "20150815-XYZ-concatenated-file.zip". A step by step hint would be great? I tried this: [Importing XML file with special tags & namespaces <abc:xyz> in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058904/importing-xml-file-with-special-tags-namespaces-abcxyz-in-mysql-using-forea) as of right now but it's not getting the job done yet!

Based on ThW explanation below I've done the following now:

```
<?php

// open input
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('./xmlreader.xml');

// open output
$output = fopen('./xmlreader.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($output, ['id', 'name']);

$xmlns = [
  'a' => 'http://www.abc-example.com'
];

// prepare DOM
$dom   = new DOMDocument;
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach ($xmlns as $prefix => $namespaceURI) {
  $xpath->registerNamespace($prefix, $namespaceURI);
}

// look for the first record element
while (
  $reader->read() && 
  (
    $reader->localName !== 'ABCRecord' || 
    $reader->namespaceURI !== $xmlns['a']
  )
) {
  continue;
}

// while you have an record element
while ($reader->localName === 'ABCRecord') {
  if ($reader->namespaceURI === 'http://www.abc-example.com') {
    // expand record element node
    $node = $reader->expand($dom);
    // fetch data and write it to output
    fputcsv(
      $output, 
      [
        $xpath->evaluate('string(a:ABC)', $node),
        $xpath->evaluate('string(a:Entity/a:LegalName)', $node)
      ]
    );
  }

  // move to the next record sibling
  $reader->next('ABCRecord');
}
```

Is this correct?! And where do I find the output?! And how do I get the output in mysql. Sorry for my rookie questions, it's the first time I'm doing this ...

```
$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "password";
$dbName = "new_xml_extract";

$dbConn = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);

$delete = $dbConn->query("TRUNCATE TABLE `test_xml`");

....

$sql = "INSERT INTO `test_xml` (`.....`, `.....`)" . "VALUES ('". $dbConn->real_escape_string($.....) ."', '".$dbConn->real_escape_string($.....)."')";

$result = $dbConn->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? have you tried using google? typing something like... how to import xml into mysql database

Comment: I did! I tried simply uploading it via the import function in mysql ... didn't work .. i tried it via the https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-xml.html .. didn't work .. I tried via PHP simplexml_load_file() Function ... that worked with a small sample xml file, but one without namespaces in it. And I was trying this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058904/importing-xml-file-with-special-tags-namespaces-abcxyz-in-mysql-using-forea, but the foreach() function lets me only do it for two tags. And if I try it with the 500MB file it freezes. It's the first time I'm doing this

Comment: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781417/importing-huge-xml-file-to-mysql

Comment: in your case you have to use a software or via terminal that will accept large files. no website is going to do this for you

Comment: I tried converting it in csv first as well (via a makro) and it work for a small amount of records, but not with the whole file. I do have a shell and terminal running. With what command could I do this and how do I need to prepare the mysql table?

Comment: I wish i could help but I haven't converted an xml file to csv or sql before. Your best bet would be to either submit a new post here or spend hours online reading other peoples methods and you'll find a solution sooner or later.

Comment: or whoever gave you the xml file have them give you an sql file instead

Comment: I'll try the new post approach first :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not know your XML structure. While it can import simple, wellformed XML structures directly, you will need to convert more complex structures yourself. You can generate CSV, SQL or a (supported) XML.

For large files like that XMLReader is the best API. First create an instance and open the file:

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('php://stdin');
```

Your are using namespaces, so I suggest defining a mapping array for them:

```
$xmlns = [
  'a' => 'http://www.abc-example.com'
];
```

It is possible to use the same prefixes/aliases as in the XML file, but you can use your own, too.

Next traverse the XML nodes until you find the first record element node:

```
while (
  $reader->read() && 
  ($reader->localName !== 'ABCRecord' ||  $reader->namespaceURI !== $xmlns['a'])
) {
  continue;
}
```

You need to compare the local name (the tag name without the namespace prefix) and the namespace URI. This way you program does not depend on the actual prefixes in the XML file.

After you found the first node, you can traverse to the next sibling with the same local name.

```
while ($reader->localName === 'ABCRecord') {
  if ($reader->namespaceURI === 'http://www.abc-example.com') {
    // read data for the record ...
  }      
  // move to the next record sibling
  $reader->next('ABCRecord');
}
```

You could use XMLReader to read the record data but it is easier with DOM and XPath expressions. XMLReader can expand the current node into a DOM node. So prepare a DOM document, create an XPath object for it and register the namespaces. Expanding a node will load the node and all descendants into memory, but not parent nodes or siblings.

```
$dom   = new DOMDocument;
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach ($xmlns as $prefix => $namespaceURI) {
  $xpath->registerNamespace($prefix, $namespaceURI);
}

while ($reader->localName === 'ABCRecord') {
  if ($reader->namespaceURI === 'http://www.abc-example.com') {
    $node = $reader->expand($dom);
    var_dump(
      $xpath->evaluate('string(a:ABC)', $node),
      $xpath->evaluate('string(a:Entity/a:LegalName)', $node)
    );
  }
  $reader->next('ABCRecord');
}
```

`DOMXPath::evaluate()` allows you to use Xpath expression to fetch scalar values or node lists from a DOM.

`fputcsv()` will it make really easy to write the data into a CSV.

Put together:

```
// open input
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('php://stdin');

// open output
$output = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
fputcsv($output, ['id', 'name']);

$xmlns = [
  'a' => 'http://www.abc-example.com'
];

// prepare DOM
$dom   = new DOMDocument;
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach ($xmlns as $prefix => $namespaceURI) {
  $xpath->registerNamespace($prefix, $namespaceURI);
}

// look for the first record element
while (
  $reader->read() && 
  (
    $reader->localName !== 'ABCRecord' || 
    $reader->namespaceURI !== $xmlns['a']
  )
) {
  continue;
}

// while you have an record element
while ($reader->localName === 'ABCRecord') {
  if ($reader->namespaceURI === 'http://www.abc-example.com') {
    // expand record element node
    $node = $reader->expand($dom);
    // fetch data and write it to output
    fputcsv(
      $output, 
      [
        $xpath->evaluate('string(a:ABC)', $node),
        $xpath->evaluate('string(a:Entity/a:LegalName)', $node)
      ]
    );
  }

  // move to the next record sibling
  $reader->next('ABCRecord');
}
```

Output:

```
id,name
5967007LIEEXZX4LPK21,"REGISTERENHETEN I Bornheim"
5967007LIE45ZX4MHC90,"SUNNDAL HOSTBANK"
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation ThW. I'm a bit confused though. Please see my edits above! Where do I find the output?! In a DOM document?! How do I do this? Is this a simple html doc?! I created a xmlreader.html ... $output = fopen('./xmlreader.html', 'w'); ... I don't see any output though! And how do I get the output into mysql from there? Sorry for my rookie question!

Comment: I used `php://stdin` and `php://stdout`. This are two "file names" for the standard input and output. This works best for online services like [eval.in](https://eval.in/419784). You changed that to a file names, but the target should be a CSV, to an HTML file. Make sure that the output file is writeable (permissions). If you write the output to a file, you can use `echo` to output status information.

Comment: I created a csv file and made sure its writeable, but still no reaction! *cry ... I'm using Netbeans, hope that's not the issue!

Comment: I can't debug your environment, my example works - you can see that here: https://eval.in/419784

Comment: That looks like UTF-8 interpreted as Latin-1. Make sure that you specify the character set/encoding while inserting.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Here is the adjustment for the Non-ASC characters: e.g. ... iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $xpath->evaluate('string(a:Entity/a:LegalName)', $node)) ... is now inserting the correct characters for most of languages. Yet, it looks like I still have some issues with JP, RU, CZ, PL and HU characters. The //TRANSLIT throws back a ? as of right now. But is there another workaround for those languages?! Regarding the issue with the number of rows: I had to increase max_input_time, max_execution_time and memory_limit and have now all the rows in csv each time I run it.

Comment: `iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", ...)` converts an UTF-8 string into ISO-8859-1 and transliterates special chars (for example `ä` to `a`). You loose them this point. Write them as UTF-8 to the CSV and make sure to provide the character set/encoding argument to the insert action/command.

Comment: Not exactly sure how "to provide the character set/encoding argument to the insert action/command." :-) Could you provide an example?!

Comment: That depends on how you insert the CSV into the database.

Comment: Oh, now I think I understand. Leave the insertion in csv like it is and when inserting the csv in mysql ... . What is the best way to insert the csv into mysql?! Similar to my other post here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058904/importing-xml-file-with-special-tags-namespaces-abcxyz-in-mysql ?

Comment: I got it! :-) Thanks a lot! One last question/wish, is it possible to have a unique record count of each row in the first column of the csv file?! And how?

Comment: Of course, it is a loop - just add a counter variable and increment it.

Comment: Could you edit the above with such a counter variable?! Thanks a lot in advance!