# How can i free busy table?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, transactions

I have **historic** table in database what is populated each 10 minutes by new data from **xml feed** using **cron**.

Xml feeds are pretty long, and my table is continuesly **busy**, i am using that table from **view** side also. 
So my processes from view side are `waiting` until process from cron finish.

What you think how i can free processes? Using multiple connections maybe or by copying data to another table what is not used by cron?

**Logic is this:**

```
FUNCTION HISTORIC TO DB
BEGIN TRY
CONNECT
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN LOOP
EXECUTE
END LOOP
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
CLOSE
END CATCH
```

**Full code:**

```
function resultsToHistoric(){
try{
    $con = new Connect();
    $countries = $this->ResultCountries;
    foreach($countries as $country){
        $this->PDO->beginTransaction();
        $path = "feeds/results/{$country}res.xml";
        $results = $this->parser->parseFile($path);
        $drzava = $this->filterCountries($results->attributes()->country).":";
        foreach($results->league as $league){
        $leagueid = $league->attributes()->id;
            $liga = $league->attributes()->name;
            $lg2 = '';
            if(!contains(strtolower($liga),strtolower($drzava))){
                $lg2 = ucfirst($drzava) . ' ' . ucfirst($liga);  
            }
            else{
                $lg2 = $liga;
            }
            //var_dump($league->stage->aggregate);
            $leaguename = $this->getMap2($lg2);
            $season = $league->attributes()->season;
            $lgstage = NULL;
            if($league->week){
              $weekroot = $league->week;
            }
            elseif($league->week){
              $weekroot = $league->week;
            }
            elseif($league->aggregate){
                $weekroot = $league->aggregate;
            }
            else{
                //$weekroot = $league->stage;
                foreach($league->stage as $stage){
                    if($stage->week){
                        $weekroot = $stage->week;
                    }
                    elseif($stage->aggregate){
                        $weekroot = $stage->aggregate;
                    }
                    else{
                        $weekroot = $league;
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach($weekroot as $week){
            $round  = 0;
            if($week->attributes()->number!=NULL){
                $round = $week->attributes()->number;
            }
            //print_r($week);
            foreach($week->match as $match){
                //var_dump($match);
                $fixid = 0;
                if($match->attributes()->id == 0 || $match->attributes()->id == ''){
                    if($match->attributes()->alternate_id == 0 || $match->attributes()->id == ''){
                        $fixid = $match->attributes()->alternate_id_2;
                    }
                    else{
                        $fixid = $match->attributes()->alternate_id;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    $fixid = $match->attributes()->id;
                }
                $dbdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($match->attributes()->date));
                $dbtime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($match->attributes()->time));

                $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($dbdate . $dbtime));
                $fcountry = $this->filterCountries($results->attributes()->country);    

                //echo $fcountry;
                //$home = $match->home->attributes()->name;
                //$away = $match->away->attributes()->name;
                $home = '';
                $away = '';
                $homeid = 0;
                $awayid = 0;
                $hgoals = 0;
                $agoals = 0;
                if($match->home){
                $home = $this->getMap($fcountry,$match->home->attributes()->name);
                $away = $this->getMap($fcountry,$match->away->attributes()->name);
                $homeid = $this->filterTeams($fcountry,$match->home->attributes()->id);
                $awayid = $this->filterTeams($fcountry,$match->away->attributes()->id); 

                $hgoals = $match->home->attributes()->score;
                $agoals = $match->away->attributes()->score;
                }

                $eventname = $home . ' - ' . $away;

                $halftimehomegoals = 0;
                $halftimeawaygoals = 0;
                if($match->halftime->attributes()->score != NULL){
                    $halftime = explode("-",$match->halftime->attributes()->score);
                    $halftimehomegoals = (int)$halftime[0];
                    if(array_key_exists(1,$halftime)){
                        $halftimeawaygoals = (int)$halftime[1];
                    }
                }

                $homescore = '';
                $awayscore = '';
                if($match->goals->goal != NULL){
                  foreach($match->goals->goal as $goal){
                      if($goal->attributes()->team == 'home'){
                         $homescore .= $goal->attributes()->minute.': '.
                         $goal->attributes()->player.'; ';
                      }
                      elseif($goal->attributes()->team == 'away'){
                         $awayscore .= $goal->attributes()->player.'; ';
                      }
                  }
                }
                $homesquad = '';
                $awaysquad = '';
                if($match->lineups != NULL){
                  foreach($match->lineups as $lineup){
                      if($lineup->home->player != NULL){
                        foreach($lineup->home->player as $player){
                            $homesquad .= $player->attributes()->name . '; ';
                        }
                      }
                      if($lineup->away->player != NULL){
                        foreach($lineup->away->player as $player){
                            $awaysquad .= $player->attributes()->name . '; ';
                        }
                      }
                  }
                }

                $homesub = '';
                $awaysub = '';
                if($match->substitutions != NULL){
                    foreach($match->substitutions as $subs){
                        if($subs->home->substitution != NULL){
                            foreach($subs->home->substitution as $sub){
                                $homesub .= $sub->attributes()->minute."' in: ".
                                $sub->attributes()->player_in_name . '; ' . ' out: ' .
                                $sub->attributes()->player_out_name . '; ';
                            }
                        }
                        if($subs->away->substitution != NULL){
                            foreach($subs->away->substitution as $sub){
                                $awaysub .= $sub->attributes()->minute."' in: ".
                                $sub->attributes()->player_in_name . '; ' .
                                $sub->attributes()->player_out_name . '; ';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                //if($homesquad!='' || $awaysquad != ''){
              $this->execHistoric($fixid,$fixid,$datetime,$round,NULL,$leaguename,$leagueid,strtolower($fcountry),$eventname, $homeid, $home, NULL, $hgoals, $halftimehomegoals,NULL,NULL,NULL,$homescore,NULL, $homesquad,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, $away, $awayid, NULL, $agoals, $halftimeawaygoals, NULL, NULL, NULL, $awayscore,NULL,$awaysquad,NULL,NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, $homesub, $awaysub,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL , 'tipgin',$season);
                //continue; 
                //}
                echo $leaguename . ' ' . $leagueid . ' ' . $fixid . ' ' . $eventname.'<br>';
                echo 'home squad: ' .$homesquad.'<br>';
                echo 'away squad: ' .$awaysquad.'<br>';
                echo 'home sub: ' .$homesub.'<br>';
                echo 'away sub: ' .$awaysub.'<br>';
                echo 'home scorers: ' .$homescore.'<br>';
                echo 'away scorers: ' .$awayscore.'<br>';
            }
             // }else continue;
            }
        }
        //error_log(" RESULT ENDED: ".$country. date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),3,'php/errorlog.txt');
        $this->PDO->commit(); //SAVE
        error_log(" ENDED HISTORIC: ".$country. date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),3,'php/errorlog.txt');
        }
        $con->close(); //CLOSE
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}
}

function execHistoric($hisid,$fixid,$date,$round,$spec,$league,$leagueid, $country, $eventname, $hteamid,$hteam,$hcorn,$hgoals,$hthgoals,$hshots,$hsont,$hfouls,$hgd,$hgk,$hdf,$hmdf,$hfw,$hls,$hlc,$hycard,$hrcard,$htf,$ateam,$ateamid,$acorn,$agoals,$athgoals,$ashots,$asont,$afouls,$agd,$agk,$adf,$amdf,$afw,$als,$alc,$aycard,$arcard,$atf,$hsubd,$asubd,$htycd,$atycd,$htrcd,$atrcd,$source,$season){
    $stmt = $this->PDO->prepare($this->insHis);
    $stmt->bindParam(':hisID', $hisid);
    $stmt->bindParam(':fixID',$fixid);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pdate',$date);
    $stmt->bindParam(':round',$round);
    $stmt->bindParam(':spectators',$spec);
    $stmt->bindParam(':league',$league);
    $stmt->bindParam(':leagueid',$leagueid);
    $stmt->bindParam(':country',$country);
    $stmt->bindParam(':eventname',$eventname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeTeam',$hteam);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeTeamID',$hteamid);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeCorners',$hcorn);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeGoals',$hgoals);
    $stmt->bindParam(':halfTimeHomeGoals', $hthgoals);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeShots', $hshots);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeShotsOnTarget', $hsont);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeFouls',$hfouls);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeGoalDetails', $hgd);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeLineupGoalkeeper',$hgk);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeLineupDefense',$hdf);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeLineupMidfield',$hmdf);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeLineupForward',$hfw);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeLineupSubstitutes',$hls);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeLineupCoach',$hlc);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeYellowCards',$hycard);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeRedCards',$hrcard);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeTeamFormation',$htf);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awayTeam',$ateam);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awayTeamID',$ateamid);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awayCorners', $acorn);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awayGoals', $agoals);
    $stmt->bindParam(':halfTimeAwayGoals', $athgoals);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awayShots',$ashots);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awayShotsOnTarget', $asont);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awayFouls',$afouls);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awayGoalDetails',$agd);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awayLineupGoalkeeper',$agk);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awayLineupDefense',$adf);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awayLineupMidfield',$amdf);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awayLineupForward',$afw);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awayLineupSubstitutes',$als);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awayLineupCoach',$alc);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awayYellowCards',$aycard);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awayRedCards',$arcard);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awayTeamFormation',$atf);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeSubDetails', $hsubd);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awaySubDetails', $asubd);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeTeamYellowCardDetails', $htycd);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awayTeamYellowCardDetails',$atycd);
    $stmt->bindParam(':homeTeamRedCardDetails', $htrcd);
    $stmt->bindParam(':awayTeamRedCardDetails', $atrcd);
    $stmt->bindParam(':source',$source);
    $stmt->bindParam(':season',$season);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Currently i solve this by killing all processes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several possible approaches. The most important is to split read and write. The Write (database insert) is blocking, loading and reading the XML is not.

You're using the SimpleXML, so you're feeds are small enough to load into memory. Check if you can convert them into an array and use the mass insert syntax.

If not you can convert them to CSV and use the command line or INSERT FROM file syntax. You can use XMLReader with DOM/SimpleXML to create the CSV. I described that in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32117345/2265374).

Another possibility would be using XSLT to convert the feeds into simple wellformed XML that is supported by MySQLs [LOAD XML syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html). XSLT is designed for that kind of job. You could merge the XML files with XMLReader/XMLWriter in a second step.

A third approach would be to insert the data into a temporary table and move them with an `INSERT INTO SELECT`.

The main target of all approaches is to minimize the statements executed on the used table. So you prepare the data in a way that you can move them into the table with a single SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @ThW i will probably try to insert data to temporary table.