# PHP handling large XML/CSV files doesn't work

Tags: php, xml

1) I have several XML files that are placed in a folder on my server.

I try to get the XML in the file like this:

```
$XML = simplexml_load_file('feeds/'.$feedfile);
```

Works great for XML files up to 30-40 MB, but it fails for XML files that are 100-200 MB or bigger.

I have tried to put the call to simplexml_load_file in a try-catch, but no error is output.

2) A similar problem is encountered when I try to explode a large CSV file (180 MB).

I try to explode the CSV like this:

```
$products = explode("\n", $feedfileData);
```

Any idea why the XML/CSV handling doesn't work?

Thanks.

---

I have tried using the XMLReader after seeing [How do I get a 50MB zip file with a 600MB xml file into a mysql datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112985/how-do-i-get-a-50mb-zip-file-with-a-600mb-xml-file-into-a-mysql-datatable)

It didn't help. When I use XMLReader on big files (185 MB), I only parse the first ~800 nodes and then the script dies.

XMLReader works on smaller files. For a 45 MB XML file, I was able to parse all the nodes in the file (10,000+ nodes).

---

Problem might be memory. Above the CSV/XML handling, I'm filling an array with lots of data from the database.

Like this:

$currentProducts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id, feedid, size, price FROM products WHERE shopid = 200");

If I put a limit on this query (SELECT ... shopid = 200 LIMIT 5000), I can parse far more nodes from the big 185 MB XML file (30,000+ nodes instead of just ~800 nodes).

I need to compare the feed products with the $currentProducts array, so I guess the question is now: How do get an array or similar to compare the feed products with that doesn't take up all the memory?

Thanks.

Comment: For csv you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php It works even for 8GB files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a 50MB zip file with a 600MB xml file into a mysql datatable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112985/how-do-i-get-a-50mb-zip-file-with-a-600mb-xml-file-into-a-mysql-datatable)

Comment: Please don't put two different problems into a single question. For CSV use `fgetscsv()` or the `splFileObject`.

Comment: Thought it could be a memory problem or something. i.e. that PHP doesn't have enough working memory to handle files this size?

Comment: No it is a conceptual problem. You're loading the whole file into the RAM. So it is limited by it. Apis like XMLReader or SPLFileObject can work on the files loading them part by part.

Comment: Have tried using XMLReader (described in my edit of the original question). I didn't work.